# DisableLoopbackCheck does not work for IIS 10 sites configured for Tomcat 10 AJP Connector

Tags: windows, iis, tomcat10

DisableLoopbackCheck is not working for IIS 10 sites configured with Tomcat 10 AJP Connector. I am able to locally authenticate into sites not configured with Tomcat on the same IIS instance using the site FQDN. I get 401.3 only for sites configured for Tomcat redirect. Below are my workers.properties and server.xml settings:

```
worker.tom9.port=7009
worker.tom9.host=my.test.com
worker.tom9.type=ajp13
worker.tom9.lbfactor=1

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" tomcatAuthentication="false" address="10.10.10.1" />
```

I wonder if anyone else came across a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. In Windows 2019, Authenticated users group needs to be granted read permission on the Tomcat folder.